# How to pass a datetime to a template using Jinja2?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I want to pass the variable `next_start` from my application.py file to the js script in a HTML template.

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_start, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
next_start = start_date + timedelta(days=cycle_avg)
return render_template("calendar.html", next_start = next_start)
```

The calendar.html file script tag:

```
<script>
    let highlight = {{ next_start }};
</script>
```

This does not seem to work; how can I pass this `datetime`?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not work. take a look at the generated script tag, and you'll see that what you've generated is not valid javascript. You want something that looks like

```
let highlight = new Date(....);
```

Comment: Your answer is missing the fact that they need to add quotes around `{{ next_start }}`, which `....` doesn't explain. Otherwise, this is indeed the correct approach. If they don't add quotes, it fails

Comment: The `....` is intended as a placeholder. The answer already says that you need to look at the generated javascript to verify that it is valid.